# not adding new line in my XSLT

Tags: xslt, newline

I am not certain why my xslt won't put a new line in my output...
This is my xslt....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="newline"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template name="FairWarningTransform" match="/">    <!--@* | node()">-->

          <xsl:for-each select="//SelectFairWarningInformationResult">  

                <xsl:value-of select="ApplicationID"/>,<xsl:value-of select="USERID"/>
                &#10;
          </xsl:for-each>

        * Note.  This report outlines Fair warning entries into reported for the above time frame.

      </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my output...

```
1,TEST1,test2,
```

I want it to look like...

```
1,TEST
1,test2,
```

Why isn't this character 
 creating a newline

Answer (score 9, accepted):

XSLT's default behavior is to ignore any text nodes in the stylesheet that are entirely whitespace (this is true even if some of the whitespace is encoded as entities like `&#10;`), except for text inside `<xsl:text>`, which is preserved.

I suggest replacing these lines:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ApplicationID"/>,<xsl:value-of select="USERID"/>
&#10;
```

with this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(ApplicationID, ',', USERID, '&#10;')"/>
```

That way the newline should be ensured to be included in the output.

Answer (score 10):

Try replacing

```
&#10;
```

with

```
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
```

That helps XSLT distinguish it from other whitespace in your stylesheet that is part of the stylesheet formatting (not part of the desired output).

Comment: I like this better because it saves one function call (`concat`).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as your newline instead of the escaped character:

```
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
```

Comment: no need for the d-o-e, it should work fine with just `<xsl:text>` (though using `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` as suggested by LarsH is more robust).

Comment: @JLRishe whitespace is preserved inside `<xsl:text>` by default anyway.

Comment: @IanRoberts True. Removed it, if that was confusing.

Comment: This doesn't work (at least in some cases). I can't explain why, but I tried it and nothing was inserted.

Comment: I found I had to do:

    ```<xsl:text xml:whitespace="preserve">
    </xsl:text>```
 as my processor wasn't applying it by default.