# XML to Text transform using XSLT with new line

Tags: xml, xslt, text, newline, xmlconvert

I looked at multiple examples and gave each on them a try. Not sure what am I missing. The only difference I found from other examples was that I have multiple `<Line>` nodes under `<RecordSet>`.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urn:FlatStructure">
  <Recordset>
    <Line> 12345678</Line>
    <Line> abcdefgh</Line>
  </Recordset>
</urn:FlatStructure>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<!-- First Trial  -->

<xsl:variable name="newline"><xsl:text>
</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/urn:FlatStructure/RecordSet">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(Line,$newline)" />
</xsl:template> 

<!-- Second Trial  -->
<xsl:template match="/urn:FlatStructure">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="RecordSet/Line" />
</xsl:template>

<!-- Third Trial  -->
<xsl:template match="/urn:FlatStructure">
<xsl:value-of select="concat(Line,'&#10;')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current text output:

```
12345678 abcdefgh
```

Desired text output :

```
12345678
abcdefgh
```

What am I missing in the XSLT ? Please let me know how can I correct it.

Thanks

I looked at the following examples (some may be duplicates) but none of them worked for me :

[XSLT to convert XML to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800269/xslt-to-convert-xml-to-text)

[Producing a new line in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723226/producing-a-new-line-in-xslt)

[how to add line breaks at the end of an xslt output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239446/how-to-add-line-breaks-at-the-end-of-an-xslt-output)

[not adding new line in my XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588509/not-adding-new-line-in-my-xslt)

Comment: Have you tried `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` as in the example you link to?

Comment: The code should be fine as written. To solve the problem we'll need to know more about exactly how you are running it: what XSLT processor, what environment, what API.

Comment: Although it may be typo in your question, bear in mind that XSLT is case-sensitive. You have `Recordset` elements in your XML (note the small `s`), but are looking for `RecordSet` elements in your XSLT.

Comment: @PM77-1, Yes I tried that one. It works if I put it between two `<xsl:value-of select="Line" />`, but that duplicates the data.

Comment: @TimC : Thanks for catching that. I fixed it but it still didn't work. I think XSLT is case insensitive. I am new to it so do not know much in detail

Comment: @MichaelKay : I am using the C# XslCompiledTransform.Transform Method `req.XMLFile.Save(sourceStream); sourceStream.Position = 0; XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(sourceStream); XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform(); myXslTrans.Load(GetXsltFilePath()); XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, null); myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Looping through each `<Line>` node under `<Recordset>` and selecting the text.

XSLT that worked:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:urn="someurn">

<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/urn:FlatStructure/Recordset">
    <xsl:for-each select="Line">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Multiple child nodes with the same name seemed to be the problem.

Thanks everyone for pitching in.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

What helped is replacing the newline variable with `&#10;` like

```
<xsl:variable name="newline"><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>
```

and as a consequence replacing

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(Line,'&#10;')" />
```

with

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(Line,$newline)" />
```

This gives the desired result.

However, you're code has some namespace issues to be resolved...
So add the `urn:` namespace to your XML

```
<urn:FlatStructure xmlns:urn="http://some.urn">
```

and XSLT like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:urn="http://some.urn">
```

and after that, remove the `urn` prefixes from the `FlatStructure` matches in the XSLT templates.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this. Forgot to mention it in the initial question.

Comment: I do have a URN. however since it was a proprietary information, I didn't include it. Does the `xmlns:urn` effects the way XSLT transforms the XML ?

Comment: @user6015642: Yes. It does affect what nodes are matched. I had to add a namespace to make your sample work at all.